# Upload specific file from computer

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

Is it possible to upload specific files from users PC to server, but WITHOUT using file form element?

I need this for my customer - he does not want to select those files from his pc.

Is it possible somehow to define value of file form element like we can for other elements?

Thank you in advance, hope that this question is not basic one.

**MORE INFORMATION:** we know that we can upload file on server, using 'file' web form element. By using this element we select file from our computer and upload it on server. Ok, but is possible to "skip" file selection, and upload specific file (files) without selecting it with file form element?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: You can't do that with PHP, JS, or JQuery. It is an extremely bad security thread if such thing is possible. Maybe a Java Applet can do that (I don't know).

Comment: Would'nt that be great, then I could control the interwebs (insert evil laugh) !

Comment: I could also create a page to grab a whole host of information from your machine - perhaps log in details, credit card numbers, love letters, your address, ... Get the idea - It would be a security problem and that is why the browser lives in a sandbox.

Comment: The answer still no, browsers won't allow that, a huge security issue is waiting for you if browsers allow that, starting form the client privacy abuse ending with having your server hacked.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to use a [signed java applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html). End user will be prompted to grant certain permissions (local file access, network access) when the applet is launched for the first time but it's possible to suppress permission requests on subsequent launches by having user check the "trust the publisher" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Not without some help from an external plugin.  The browser has the file element locked down because it would be a security risk to allow any website to automatically upload a file from your computer.

EDIT:
Now that I see what you want to accomplish, why go through the browser?  Why not setup some sort of synchronization between his computer in the server that doesn't go through the web?

Comment: I know there is security risk, because end user must be awared that some files will be uploaded on server (and he will be, no worries about that). Maybe to use FTP connection?

Comment: @user198003 - Even with FTP the user has to specify (or script it) to upload files. The user has ownership of the data on their machine and therefore has control over it.

Comment: He needs three files to upload on server without selecting them. He will do it every day, and he does not want to think about them, and to browse for them. I need solution how he can be released to browse and select those files.

Comment: why through the browser? because those files will contain some informations that will be parsed (by php) and submitted into mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be selected in order to be encrypted, the encryption consists of it's data, so for security reasons browsers doesn't allow default values not to have file injections, so the answer is no, you still need to use `<input type="file">` with no default value, [read this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t159949-value-attribute-in-element-input-type-file.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `name` attribute in the `input` element, and tell the customer use a suitable version of Opera that supports the attribute. Something like Opera 7. Might be hard to find.

I know that this answer may sound sarcastic, but this hopefully illustrates the situation: file input was originally designed to allow a default filename to be specified, this was implemented in some browsers only for some period of time, and now the excuse is “security”, i.e. browser vendors did not want to implement suitable security precautions and they describe the issue as if the *idea* itself were “insecure.”